# This site can’t be reached 127.0.0.1 refused to connect flask

Tags: python, docker, sqlite, flask, redis

I am trying to dockerize a flask project with Redis and SQLite. I kept getting this error when I run the project using docker. The project works just fine when I run it normally using **python manage.py run**

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.7.2-slim
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app

RUN pip install --upgrade pip

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 5000

CMD ["python","manage.py run", "--host=0.0.0.0"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  sqlite3:
    image: nouchka/sqlite3:latest
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - ./db/:/root/db/
  api:
    container_name: flask-container
    build: .
    entrypoint: python manage.py run
    env_file:
      - app/main/.env
    ports:
      - '5000:5000'
    volumes:
      - ./db/:/root/db/
      - ./app/main/:/app/main/
  redis:
    image: redis
    container_name: redis-container
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
```

Please what could be the problem?

Comment: `Please what could be the problem?` <= What does the problem actually looks like ? You are vaguely giving some error message in your title but we have absolutely no idea where it's coming from, where you read it, in which log/tool, when doing which action... Please read [How to ask](/help/how-to-ask) and [Creating an mcve](/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Your `docker-compose.yml` file has several overrides that fundamentally change the way the image works.  In particular, the `entrypoint:` line suppresses the `CMD` from the Dockerfile, which loses the key `--host` option.  You also should not need `volumes:` to inject the application code (it's already in the image), nor should you need to manually specify `container_name:`.

```yaml
services:
  api:
    build: .
    env_file:
      - app/main/.env
    ports:
      - '5000:5000'
    # and no other settings
```

In the Dockerfile, your `CMD` has two shell words combined together.  You need to split those up into separate words in the JSON-array syntax.

```sh
CMD ["python","manage.py", "run", "--host=0.0.0.0"]
#                       ^^^^ two words
```

With these two fixes, you'll be running the `CMD` from the image, with the code built into the image, and with the critical `--host=0.0.0.0` option.

Comment: I kept getting this error `------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c pip install -r requirements.txt]: error creating overlay mount to /var/lib/docker/overlay2/5cp4rbmulpr8qgom9n46cgtpu/merged: invalid argument
ERROR: Service 'api' failed to build : Build failed`